# JPA inheritance of subclass

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

Imagine that we have :

```
public class Person {...}
public class Employee extends Person {....}
```

We make of Employee an entity that have an other table as Person.
With JPA we make our interface extends JpaRepository.

I ask the `personRepo.findAll()`

Is it possible to get only the List of Person without the Employees?
(I'm analysing this atm so I don't have concreet example, just need to know if this is possible)

Thx in advance

Comment: Show us more code please.

Comment: rephrased mine question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the same thing.
This is my code:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Audited
public abstract class AbstractUser{..}

@Entity
@Audited
public class Admin extends AbstractUser{ .. }

@Entity
@Audited
public class OtherUser extends AbstractUser{ .. }
```

And then, I use Repository too.
So if I use `yoursRepository.findAll();` I get all Users..

In your case, with `personRepo.findAll(),` you get all person.. **You get all those that extend person and those that do not extend it.**

**EDIT: after question edit**
If you want get only employee you can use two different repository, one for Employee and one for Person. So when you use employeeRepository, you get only employee..

Comment: Yeah I was afraid of that, so I have to implement the abstract class to. (I hoped to do without it)

Comment: Yes that I know, I was only trying not to have the abstract class. This is because the problem is that the extended class a backupclass must be of the first class (only with 3 extra fields like user, date and an Id)